# Why it is a UIView instead of UIViewController in the xib of UIViewController's subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib

When I newly created a subview of `UIViewController` along with `xib` file, I find it is a `UIView` but not a `UIViewController` in the `xib` file.
So why Xcode implement the xib file like this? What is the purpose?

**Newly created class:-**

[image]

**The xib file:-**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is type of `UIViewController` just select the `File'S Owner` after that check the `identity inspector`, you see that it has the set the class `NewViewController` like this image.

[image]

Also check selecting your `view` after that check the `connection inspector`, you see it is connected with the `File's Owner view` like this image.

[image]

Comment: i know, so that view is connected with the `NewViewController's` `self.view`. Now you getting.

Comment: You are right. Xcode linked the view, file owner, and the NewVIewController class. But in this way, it always causes some bugs.So every time, I'll delete the view and "NewViewController" name in file owner's `identity inspector`, and drag a new UIViewController by myself, and fill in "NewVIewController" at UIViewController's `identity inspector`. It's quite annoying.

Comment: You cannot add `UIViewController` inside `XIB`, you need to added `UIView` and connect it with the FIle's Owner view.

Comment: But I always add `UIViewController` into `XIB`, like this: [one of my xib](http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/large/825a0258gw1f6z2ycr5iwj218408k76e.jpg)

Comment: Yes you are right, but i am talking about xib file that you have created with `NewViewController` that needs connect with the view, not `ViewController`.

Comment: If not doing like this, I will meet problem. For example, when I want to push this `UIViewController` into a `NavigationController`, it went wrong.